# List and use Application Roles using WLST - listAppRoles()

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst, oas

Is there a possibility to list up and work with existing Application Roles?
I want to list up my roles and then check afterwards the member of this roles with listAppRoleMembers(appStripe='obi', appRoleName='XY').
But first things first...
Has someone find a way to get this lines?

I tried things like:

```
import sys
    import os
    
    try:
      myRoles = []
      for line in listAppRoles( appStripe='obi'):
       myRoles.append(line)
      print myRoles
    except Exception, e:
     print e
    
    exit ()
```

Br.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: +1 to the community bot. What you're asking for is very unclear. "my roles" meaning the ones YOU have as a user or "all the app roles in my system".